# How to start a piped child process so that process.stdout.columns still work?

Tags: node.js

```
//   test.js

if (process.argv.indexOf('child') >= 0) {
    console.log('child columns:', process.stdout.columns)
}
else {
    console.log('parent columns:', process.stdout.columns)
    pipedExec('node', ['test.js', 'child'], function(outdata) {
        console.log('   '+outdata.join('\n   '))
    })
}

function pipedExec (cmd, arg, callback) {
    var
        pipe = '',
        spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        x = spawn(cmd, arg)
    function d(outdata) { pipe += outdata.toString() }
    x.stdout.on('data', d) 
    x.stderr.on('data', d)
    x.on('close', function() { callback(pipe.split('\n')) })
    return x
}
```

---

Here is the output:

```
$ node test.js 
parent columns: 104
   child columns: undefined
```

How to make this code work as expected, i.e. let the child get the correct value from `process.stdout.columns`? I can inherit handles, but then piping will not work. Or I can pass the column counter in the program args or via the file (which I currently do), but I would like to simply set the pipe's column width some how, if that is possible.